# Discord Bot con cURL en C

Tags: c, post, curl

Estoy intentando crear un bot para Discord en C ([libdiscord](https://github.com/dxing97/libdiscord) crashea constantemente). Mi idea es no solo escribir mensajes, sino también leerlos (pero por ahora tengo suficiente con escribir).

Buscando como enviar mensajes, encontré este código funcional en Python:

```
import requests
import json

channelID = "..."
botToken = "..."

baseURL = f"https://discordapp.com/api/channels/{channelID}/messages"
headers = { "Authorization":f"Bot {botToken}",
            "User-Agent":"myBotThing (http://some.url, v0.1)",
            "Content-Type":"application/json", }

message = "hello world"

POSTedJSON =  json.dumps ( {"content":message} )

r = requests.post(baseURL, headers = headers, data = POSTedJSON)
```

Luego intenté pasarlo en C, usando cURL (al principio usaba sockets, pero con el HTTPS no funcionaba).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

    const char *ID = "...";
    const char *token = "...";
    char *post_body = "{ \"content\" : \"hello world\" }";

    char tmp[1024];


    // curl handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:"); // init

        sprintf(tmp, "https://discordapp.com/api/channels/%s/messages", ID);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, tmp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "myBotThing (http://some.url, v0.1)");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        // POST
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_body);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

        // header
        sprintf(tmp, "Authorization: Bot %s", token);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, tmp);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        sprintf(tmp, "Host: https://discordapp.com/api/channels/%s/messages", ID);
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, tmp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);


        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // error?
        if(res != CURLE_OK) printf("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

        // free
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que no logro hacer que funcione (error 400, bad request), pero creo que sí lo identifica (si no saldría acceso denegado).

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en esta parte:

```
sprintf(tmp, "Host: https://discordapp.com/api/channels/%s/messages", ID);
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, tmp);
```

La cabecera *Host* debe ser el dominio o la dirección IP del servidor, no una
URL. Entonces basta con poner el dominio de Discord:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Host: discordapp.com");
```

Un consejo aparte, en el futuro usar un *proxy* local te puede ayudar a depurar
situaciones como esta. Como envias una petición en Python o en C, si
configuras el *proxy* para que intercepte las peticiones HTTP luego puedes
comparar los encabezados y el contenido de cada petición y ver la diferencia.
Dos *proxies* que podrías usar son [*OWASP ZAP*](https://www.zaproxy.org/) o
[*mitmproxy*](https://mitmproxy.org/).

Comment: Ahora me da error 10003, Unknown Channel. He probado mitmproxy, pero no captura HTTPS.